# Is it possible to compose multiple interpreters for my Free Monad scala app

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, free-monad

So i started to learn free monadic approach in my code style recently, and i hope i get the main idea of it. We have our own dsl to build a program, then we pass a compiler to a real world effect such as cats.IO and it looks good in simple programs such as calculator or smth but when i tried to build a real world app, such as http server with multiple domains (Postgress adt: get, post, delete, update. Config adt: read. HttpServer adt: start) and many more, i can't understand, how to compose a program with multiple dsls.

cats off doc says to try (`type CatsApp[A] = EitherK[DataOp, Interact, A]`) which is kind of a thing i've been looking for, but so far it only says how to compose 2 compilers into 1.

i either need a solution to compose any amount compilers or i have to build a huge ass adt which can do anything

```scala
object ConfigADT {
  type Config[A] = Free[ConfigA, A]
  sealed trait ConfigA[A]
  case class Read[T]() extends ConfigA[T]
  def read[A]: Config[A] = liftF[ConfigA, A](Read[A]())
}

object ServerADT {
  type Server[A] = Free[ServerA, A]
  sealed trait ServerA[A]
  case class Start[T, C](config: C) extends ServerA[T]
  def start[A, C](config: C): Server[A] = liftF[ServerA, A](Start[A, C](config))
}

object VictoriaMetricsADT {
  type VictoriaMetrics[T] = Free[VictoriaMetricsA, T]
  sealed trait VictoriaMetricsA[T]
  case class Query[T, C](query: String)(config: C) extends VictoriaMetricsA[T]
  case class Put[T, C](value: T)(config: C) extends VictoriaMetricsA[Unit]
  def query[T, C](query: String)(config: C): VictoriaMetrics[T] = liftF[VictoriaMetricsA, T](Query[T, C](query)(config))
  def put[T, C](value: T)(config: C): VictoriaMetrics[Unit] = liftF[VictoriaMetricsA, Unit](Put[T, C](value)(config))
}
```

i want to make a program which will read a config then start a server and server will use victoria dsl

```scala
for {
 config <- ConfigADT.read[ConfigData]
 dataFromVictoria <- VictoriaADT.query("my query")(config)
 server <- ServerADT.start(config)
} yield ()
```

i understand, code is very abstract, but i hope i showed you the main idea what i'm trying to do.

i might not fully understood the concept of multiple programs combining into big one. I'm still thinking to compile some parts of it in the middle, so i can compose it using IO. Please help my stupid head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, surely it's possible to compose multiple interpreters.

Your code corresponds to the section [Free your ADT](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html#free-your-adt). But you should use written in the next section [Composing Free monads ADTs](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html#composing-free-monads-adts), just not for `EitherK[Algebra1, Algebra2, A]` but for `EitherK[Algebra1, EitherK[Algebra2, Algebra3, *], A]`

```
import cats.{Id, InjectK, ~>}
import cats.data.EitherK
import cats.free.Free

// the 1st ADT
sealed trait Config[A]
case class Read[T]() extends Config[T]

class Configs[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[Config, F]) {
  def read[T](): Free[F, T] = Free.liftInject[F][Config, T](Read[T]())
}
object Configs {
  implicit def configs[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[Config, F]): Configs[F] = new Configs[F]
}

// the 2nd ADT
sealed trait Server[A]
case class Start[T, C](config: C) extends Server[T]

class Servers[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[Server, F]) {
  def start[T, C](config: C): Free[F, T] = Free.liftInject[F][Server, T](Start[T, C](config))
}
object Servers {
  implicit def servers[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[Server, F]): Servers[F] = new Servers[F]
}

// the 3rd ADT
sealed trait VictoriaMetric[T]
case class Query[T, C](query: String, config: C) extends VictoriaMetric[T]
case class Put[T, C](value: T, config: C) extends VictoriaMetric[Unit]

class VictoriaMetrics[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[VictoriaMetric, F]) {
  def query[T, C](query: String, config: C): Free[F, T] = Free.liftInject[F][VictoriaMetric, T](Query[T, C](query, config))
  def put[T, C](value: T, config: C): Free[F, Unit] = Free.liftInject[F][VictoriaMetric, Unit](Put[T, C](value, config))
}
object VictoriaMetrics {
  implicit def victoriaMetrics[F[_]](implicit I: InjectK[VictoriaMetric, F]): VictoriaMetrics[F] = new VictoriaMetrics[F]
}

//interpreters
object ConfigInterpreter extends (Config ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: Config[A]): A = fa match {
    case Read() => ???
  }
}

object ServerInterpreter extends (Server ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: Server[A]): A = fa match {
    case Start(config) => ???
  }
} 

object VictoriaMetricInterpreter extends (VictoriaMetric ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: VictoriaMetric[A]): A = fa match {
    case Query(query, config) => ???
    case Put(value, config)   => ()
  }
}

case class ConfigData()
case class FromVictoriaData()

def program[F[_]](implicit
  C: Configs[F],
  S: Servers[F],
  V: VictoriaMetrics[F]
): Free[F, Unit] = for {
  config           <- C.read[ConfigData]()
  dataFromVictoria <- V.query[FromVictoriaData, ConfigData]("my query", config)
  server           <- S.start[Unit, ConfigData](config)
} yield ()

type CatsApp[A] = EitherK[Config, EitherK[Server, VictoriaMetric, *], A]

val interpreter: CatsApp ~> Id = ConfigInterpreter or (ServerInterpreter or VictoriaMetricInterpreter)

val evaled: Unit = program[CatsApp].foldMap(interpreter)
```

https://medium.com/@olxc/the-evolution-of-a-scala-programmer-1b7a709fb71f#2de0